# Win Svr 08 R2 - IIS 7.5 - All sites went down after change without full privlidges

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

Server: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard SP 1 - 64bit
IIS: 7.5

3 websites hosted from these locations:

```
D:\WebApplications\TestAccessManager
D:\WebApplications\dg
D:\WebApplications\TestVM
```

All Application Pools are up and running, and have been restarted.

All Sites are up and running, and have been restarted. (a total of 7 sites, just don't need to list everything).

The "default website" points to `\TestVM` and has no DNS name, it is only accessed by IP address.

The second site `test.accessmanager.com`, and the third site `test.dg.com`.

6 of the 7 sites are inaccessible. The one that can be accessed, the default website, is accessed by IP.

---

**Now, how this all started.**

Yesterday a user account was setup for me to access this server.

Another developer wanted to put a secondary site as a sub-site within default website, so the files were all dropped into a child folder: `TestVM\subsite\`.   However, because the subsite has a web.config, I then created a Virtual Directory and pointed it to that sub folder. We then started having even more issues, so I right clicked on the Virtual Directory and hit "Remove".

Next, we were told that both dg and accessmanager were down.  So I removed the `\subsite\` folder completely to eliminate that from the equation... but to no avail.

Now, the kicker to all of this... is that the user account I had been given, apparently didn't have admin privileges... which would explain why certain folders would prompt "You don't currently have permission to access this folder. Click Continue to permanently get access to this folder".

One of our guys here says that without full authority, certain registry keys could have gotten messed up while working in IIS, and that he's seen it happen in the past, and never successfully had it fixed without just recreating all the virtual sites and "starting from scratch" in IIS.

Thoughts? Need more info? Anything?